# SNMP4j + responsePdu arrival time

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

Is there a way to find out what is the arrival time of responsePdu? I send an asynchronous request and would like to know when the response pdu has reached my server.
In whireshark this data are available but I cannot read it using snmp4j library. Any help appreciated:)